# cassandra nodes unresponsive due to high number of Native-Transport-Requests

Tags: cassandra

This is second time i am posting about this issue.

For every couple of days we are noticing high number of ACTIVE "Native-Transport-Requests" count (around 100 to 200) in "nodetool tpstats" output. This happens randomly on couple of nodes in Single DC (we have 6 nodes). When that happens application is slow.

We started noticing the above issue after deploying the new micro-services in production.

We deployed same micro-services in another production cluster but they don't have above explained issue.

we are using Apache Cassandra 2.2.8 version.

Here are the settings we already have in cluster.

In **Cassandra.yaml** file, we have **native_transport_max_threads: 1024**. In **Cassandra-env.sh** file we have
**JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -da -server -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data1/tmp -Dcassandra.max_queued_native_transport_requests=4096**

When i check number of incoming connections with below command on all nodes

**netstat -tupawn | grep 9042 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l**

I see more than almost 1131 connections per node.

we don't have high GC pauses. I see GC pause is below 400 ms on all nodes.

1. Now should I increase native_transport_max_threads to 1200? because we're having 1131 connections per node? and max_queued_native_transport_requests to 5192?
2. On the other cluster, we have native_transport_max_threads: 512 and number of incoming CQL connections are more 5000+ but we're not seeing the above explained issue in this cluster.